# The first time a menu is clicked by touch, show the sub menu. The second time a menu is clicked by touch, open the link of the anchor tag

Tags: angularjs

When a menu is hovered by a mouse, show the sub-menu.
When a menu is clicked with a mouse, open the link of the anchor tag.
The first time a menu is clicked by touch, show the sub menu.
The second time a menu is clicked by touch, open the link of the anchor tag.
Switch functionality seamlessly for tablets that also have mouse devices attached.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I am facing a problem in touch devices(mobiles). For the desktop the menus are working fine on hover the sub menus are shown. but for the mobiles there is no hover effects, so we need to tap on menu, but instead of opening the sub menu on first time, it redirects to link which is provided.

Comment: When a menu is hovered by a mouse, show the sub-menu.
When a menu is clicked with a mouse, open the link of the anchor tag.
The first time a menu is clicked by touch, show the sub menu.
The second time a menu is clicked by touch, open the link of the anchor tag.